# Django testing models.py file

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-testing, test-coverage

I am performing the Django for my models.py file

Here is my models.py file

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime

from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from django.apps import apps
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, post_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django_google_maps import fields as map_fields
from django_mysql.models import ListTextField
from simple_history.models import HistoricalRecords

from farm_management import config
from igrow.utils import get_commodity_name, get_region_name, get_farmer_name, get_variety_name

db_config = settings.USERS_DB_CONNECTION_CONFIG


class Device(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    fetch_status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    last_fetched_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    geolocation = map_fields.GeoLocationField(max_length=100)
    device_status = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=config.DEVICE_STATUS, default='new')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    history = HistoricalRecords()


class Farm(models.Model):
    farmer_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()  # User for which farm is created
    irrigation_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=config.IRRIGATION_TYPE_CHOICE)
    soil_test_report = models.CharField(max_length=512, null=True, blank=True)
    water_test_report = models.CharField(max_length=512, null=True, blank=True)
    farm_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=config.FARM_TYPE_CHOICE)
    franchise_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=config.FRANCHISE_TYPE_CHOICE)
    total_acerage = models.FloatField(help_text="In Acres", null=True, blank=True,
                                      validators=[MaxValueValidator(1000000), MinValueValidator(0)])
    farm_status = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="pipeline", choices=config.FARM_STATUS_CHOICE)
    assignee_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  # Af team user to whom farm is assigned.
    previous_crop_ids = ListTextField(base_field=models.IntegerField(), null=True, blank=True, size=None)
    sr_assignee_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    lgd_state_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    district_code = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    sub_district_code = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    village_code = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    farm_network_code = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True, blank=True)
    farm_health = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(100), MinValueValidator(0.1)],
                                      help_text="In Percentage", null=True, blank=True)
    soil_k = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Soil (K)", null=True, blank=True)
    soil_n = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Soil (N)", null=True, blank=True)
    soil_p = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Soil (P)", null=True, blank=True)
    water_ec = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Water (ec)", null=True, blank=True)
    water_ph = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Water (pH)", null=True, blank=True)
    soil_test_report_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    water_test_report_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    pest_problems = models.TextField(verbose_name="Pest Problems (If Any)", null=True, blank=True)
    onboarded_by_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    farm_image = models.CharField(max_length=512, null=True, blank=True)
    updated_by_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_by_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    device_id = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="farm", null=True, blank=True,
                                  db_column='device_id')
    boundary_coord = models.TextField(verbose_name="Boundary of Farm", null=True, blank=True)
    lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=22, decimal_places=16, blank=True, null=True)
    lng = models.DecimalField(max_digits=22, decimal_places=16, blank=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    region_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    farmer_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    farm_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    pending_tasks = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    batch_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    locality = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    history = HistoricalRecords()

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['farmer_id']),
            models.Index(fields=['assignee_id']),
            models.Index(fields=['sr_assignee_id'])
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.farm_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.lgd_state_id:
            region_name = get_region_name(self.lgd_state_id)
            if region_name:
                self.region_name = region_name[0]
        if self.farmer_id:
            farmer_name = get_farmer_name(self.farmer_id, 'name')
            if not farmer_name.empty:
                self.farmer_name = farmer_name[0]
                self.farm_name = "{}'s farm".format(self.farmer_name)
                if self.total_acerage:
                    self.farm_name += " - {} acres".format(self.total_acerage)
        super(Farm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def update_pending_tasks(self):
        BatchSOPManagement = apps.get_model('sop_management', 'BatchSOPManagement')
        self.pending_tasks = BatchSOPManagement.objects.filter(batch_id__farm_id=self.id, current_status=2,
                                                               due_datetime__lt=datetime.today()).count()
        self.save()

    def update_batch_count(self):
        Batch = apps.get_model('farm_management', 'Batch')
        self.batch_count = Batch.objects.filter(farm_id=self.id).count()
        self.save()

    def update_farm_health(self):
        Batch = apps.get_model('farm_management', 'Batch')
        farm_health = [batch.batch_health * batch.acerage for batch in Batch.objects.filter(farm_id=self.id) if
                       batch.acerage and batch.batch_health]
        total_acerage = sum([batch.acerage for batch in Batch.objects.filter(farm_id=self.id) if batch.acerage])
        if total_acerage:
            self.farm_health = sum(farm_health) / total_acerage
            self.save()


class HistoricalCropInfo(models.Model):
    historical_yield_per_acre = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Yield / Acre - Historical")
    commodity_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    commodity_variety_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    farm_id = models.ForeignKey(Farm, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="hist_crops", db_column='farm_id')
    history = HistoricalRecords()


class Batch(models.Model):
    commodity_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    commodity_variety_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    farm_id = models.ForeignKey(Farm, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="batches", null=True, blank=True,
                                db_column='farm_id')
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    acerage = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Batch Acerage', help_text="In Acres;To change this value go to farms>crop"
                                , validators=[MaxValueValidator(1000000), MinValueValidator(0.01)])
    batch_health = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(100), MinValueValidator(0)],
                                       help_text="In Percentage", default=100, null=True, blank=True)
    stage = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=config.STAGE_CHOICES, default='germination', null=True, blank=True)
    expected_delivery_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    current_pdd = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    historic_pdd = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    current_gdd = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    historic_gdd = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    sub_farmer_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    batch_status = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=config.BATCH_STATUS, default='to_start')
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_by_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_by_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    historical_yield_per_acre = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Yield / Acre - Historical", null=True, blank=True)
    expected_produce = models.FloatField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    actual_produce = models.FloatField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    sop_adherence = models.FloatField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    actual_yield_per_acre = models.FloatField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    commodity_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    batch_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    batch_median_health = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    pending_tasks = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    history = HistoricalRecords()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.batch_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        SOPMaster = apps.get_model('sop_management', 'SOPMaster')
        BatchSOPManagement = apps.get_model('sop_management', 'BatchSOPManagement')
        batch_sop_list = []
        if self.batch_status is 'completed':
            self.update_batch_end_date()
        self.commodity_name = self.update_commodity_name()
        self.batch_median_health = self.update_batch_median_health()
        self.batch_name = self.update_batch_name()
        super(Batch, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def update_commodity_name(self):
        if self.commodity_id:
            commodity_name = get_commodity_name(self.commodity_id)
            if commodity_name:
                return commodity_name[0]
        return None

    def update_batch_median_health(self):
        if self.start_date and self.expected_delivery_date:
            start_date = datetime.combine(self.start_date, datetime.min.time())
            expected_delivery_date = datetime.combine(self.expected_delivery_date, datetime.min.time())
            end_date = min([expected_delivery_date, datetime.today()]) - relativedelta(hours=5, minutes=30)
            hours_diff = int((((end_date - start_date).total_seconds()) / 3600 / 2))
            median_date = start_date + relativedelta(hours=hours_diff)
            try:
                median_crop_health = self.history.as_of(median_date).crop_health
            except:
                median_crop_health = self.batch_health
            return median_crop_health
        else:
            return None

    def update_batch_name(self):
        batch_name = "({}) {}".format(self.id, self.commodity_name)
        if self.start_date:
            batch_name += " | {}".format(self.start_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
        return batch_name

    def update_expected_delivery_date(self):
        self.expected_delivery_date = max([batch_yield.expected_delivery_date for batch_yield in
                                           self.batch_yields.all() if batch_yield.expected_delivery_date])
        self.save()

    def update_batch_status(self):
        number_of_yields = self.batch_yields.all().count()
        end_date_list = len([batch_yield for batch_yield in self.batch_yields.all() if
                             batch_yield.end_date and batch_yield.end_date.date() < datetime.today().date()])
        if number_of_yields == end_date_list:
            self.batch_status = 3
            self.save()

    def update_expected_produce(self):
        self.expected_produce += sum([batch_yields.expected_production for batch_yields in self.batch_yields.all()
                                      if not batch_yields.end_date])
        self.save()

    def update_actual_produce(self):
        for batch_yields in self.batch_yields.all():
            produce = 0
            if batch_yields.grade_a_produce:
                produce += batch_yields.grade_a_produce
            if batch_yields.grade_b_produce:
                produce += batch_yields.grade_b_produce
            if batch_yields.grade_c_rejection:
                produce += batch_yields.grade_c_rejection
            self.actual_produce += produce
            self.save()

    def update_sop_adherence(self):
        if self.batch_sop_management.all():
            total_sop = self.batch_sop_management.filter(due_datetime__lte=datetime.today())
            complete_sop = total_sop.filter(current_status=3)
            if total_sop:
                self.sop_adherence = complete_sop.count() / total_sop.count() * 100
                self.save()

    def update_actual_yield_per_acre(self):
        batch_actual_produce = 0
        for batch_yields in self.batch_yields.all():
            actual_produce = 0
            if batch_yields.end_date and batch_yields.end_date.date() <= datetime.today().date():
                if batch_yields.grade_a_produce:
                    actual_produce += batch_yields.grade_a_produce
                if batch_yields.grade_b_produce:
                    actual_produce += batch_yields.grade_b_produce
                if batch_yields.grade_c_rejection:
                    actual_produce += batch_yields.grade_c_rejection
            batch_actual_produce += actual_produce
        if self.acerage and batch_actual_produce:
            self.actual_yield_per_acre = batch_actual_produce / self.acerage
            self.save()

    def update_batch_end_date(self):
        batch_yields = self.batch_yields.order_by('-end_date')
        if batch_yields.exists():
            batch_yields_id = batch_yields.filter(end_date__isnull=False)
            if batch_yields_id.exists():
                self.end_date = batch_yields[0].end_date
            else:
                self.end_date = datetime.now()
        else:
            raise ValidationError("Batch yield end date does not exists")

    def update_pending_tasks(self):
        BatchSOPManagement = apps.get_model('sop_management', 'BatchSOPManagement')
        self.pending_tasks = BatchSOPManagement.objects.filter(batch_id=self.id, current_status=2,
                                                               due_datetime__lt=datetime.today()).count()
        self.save()


class BatchYield(models.Model):
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_by_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_by_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    expected_production = models.FloatField(default=0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(1000000000), MinValueValidator(0)],
                                            null=True, blank=True)
    grade_a_produce = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Grade A - Produce', default=0, null=True, blank=True,
                                        validators=[MaxValueValidator(1000000000), MinValueValidator(0)])
    grade_b_produce = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Grade B - Produce', default=0, null=True, blank=True,
                                        validators=[MaxValueValidator(1000000000), MinValueValidator(0)])
    grade_c_rejection = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Grade C - Rejection', default=0, null=True, blank=True,
                                          validators=[MaxValueValidator(1000000000), MinValueValidator(0)])
    expected_delivery_date = models.DateTimeField()
    batch_id = models.ForeignKey(Batch, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="batch_yields", db_column='batch_id')
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(help_text="Fill this date when this yield is realised with final date", null=True,
                                    blank=True)
    grade_a_sell_price = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='Grade A Sell Price', decimal_places=2, max_digits=7,
                                             null=True, blank=True)
    grade_b_sell_price = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='Grade B Sell Price', decimal_places=2, max_digits=7,
                                             null=True, blank=True)
    expected_grade_a_produce = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=12, null=True, blank=True)
    expected_grade_b_produce = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=12, null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    history = HistoricalRecords()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(BatchYield, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def update_expected_grade_produce(self):
        batch_median_health = self.batch_id.batch_median_health
        if batch_median_health:
            if batch_median_health == 100:
                grade_a_percentage = 60
                grade_b_percentage = 40
            elif 90 <= batch_median_health < 100:
                grade_a_percentage = 50
                grade_b_percentage = 50
            elif 85 <= batch_median_health < 90:
                grade_a_percentage = 45
                grade_b_percentage = 55
            elif 80 <= batch_median_health < 85:
                grade_a_percentage = 40
                grade_b_percentage = 60
            elif 70 <= batch_median_health < 80:
                grade_a_percentage = 30
                grade_b_percentage = 70
            elif 65 <= batch_median_health < 70:
                grade_a_percentage = 20
                grade_b_percentage = 80
            else:
                grade_a_percentage = 0
                grade_b_percentage = 100
            self.expected_grade_a_produce = grade_a_percentage * self.expected_production / 100
            self.expected_grade_b_produce = grade_b_percentage * self.expected_production / 100
            self.save()


class batchActualProduce(models.Model):
    harvest_date = models.DateField()
    batch_produce = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    grade = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    batch_id = models.ForeignKey(Batch, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="batch_produce", db_column='batch_id')


class Microbes(models.Model):
    microbe_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    product_code = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    beneficial_organism = models.TextField("beneficial_organism", null=True, blank=True)
    product_nomenclature = models.TextField("product_nomenclature", null=True, blank=True)
    utilization = models.TextField("uti", null=True, blank=True)
    yield_increase = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    savings = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    fk_crop_id = models.IntegerField()
    fk_region_id = models.IntegerField()
    recommended_utilization = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=True)
    remedy = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    history = HistoricalRecords()

    class Meta:
        db_table = "microbes"

    @property
    def region_name(self):
        """function to return region_name based on lgd_state_id"""
        if self.fk_region_id:
            region_name = get_region_name(self.fk_region_id)
            if region_name:
                return region_name[0]
        return None

    @property
    def commodity_name(self):
        """function to return commodity_name based on commodity_id"""
        if self.fk_crop_id:
            commodity_name = get_commodity_name(self.fk_crop_id)
            if commodity_name:
                return commodity_name[0]
        return None

    @property
    def remedy_name(self):
        """function to return commodity_name based on commodity_id"""
        remedy_name = ""
        if self.remedy:
            remedy_id_list = str(self.remedy).split(",")
            remedy_name = ",".join(x.name for x in OrganismMapping.objects.filter(id__in=remedy_id_list))
        return remedy_name


class MicrobesMapping(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    microbe_id = models.ForeignKey(Microbes, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="microbes_mapping",
                                   db_column='microbe_id')
    zone_com_microbe_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    remedy = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    history = HistoricalRecords()


class OrganismMapping(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.TextField()
    status = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    history = HistoricalRecords()


class CropAttributes(models.Model):
    commodity_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    state_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    variety_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    season_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    attribute_value = models.FloatField()
    attribute_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    attribute_unit = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=True, blank=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def commodity_name(self):
        """
        function to return commodity_name based on commodity_id
        """
        if self.commodity_id:
            commodity_name = get_commodity_name(self.commodity_id)
            if commodity_name:
                return commodity_name[0]
        return None

    @property
    def state_name(self):
        """
        function to return region_name based on lgd_state_id
        """
        if self.state_id:
            state_name = get_region_name(self.state_id)
            if state_name:
                return state_name[0]
        return None

    @property
    def variety_name(self):
        """
        function to return variety_name based on variety_id
        """
        if self.variety_id:
            variety_name = get_variety_name(self.variety_id)
            if variety_name:
                return variety_name[0]
        return None


class CropAttributesMaster(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


@receiver([post_save, post_delete], sender=BatchYield)
def expected_delivery_date_update(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    try:
        sys.setrecursionlimit(120)
        instance.batch_id.update_expected_delivery_date()
        instance.batch_id.update_batch_status()
        # instance.batch_id.update_expected_produce()
        instance.batch_id.update_actual_produce()
        instance.batch_id.update_sop_adherence()
        instance.batch_id.update_actual_yield_per_acre()
        instance.update_expected_grade_produce()
    except:
        pass


@receiver([post_save, post_delete], sender=Batch)
def update_batch_count(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.farm_id.update_batch_count()


@receiver(post_save, sender=Batch)
def update_farm_health(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.farm_id.update_farm_health()
```

I have a coverage report which helps to find which part of my code requires testing

now I am stuck at testing and could not figure out how to do the testing of it

I am sharing the coverage report screenshot the red sign indicates the code to be tested

[Screenshot of code that requires  testing click on it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9NDv.png)

I have done some testing till now here are the codes for test_farm.py

```
from datetime import datetime

from django import apps
from django.test import TestCase
from django.db.utils import IntegrityError

from farm_management.models import Farm, Device, BatchYield, Batch



class TestFarm(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):

        self.farm1 = Farm.objects.create(
            farmer_id="1",
            farmer_name="Vijay Kumar",
            irrigation_type="drip",
            farm_type="soil",
            franchise_type="protected",
            total_acerage="20",
            farm_status="pipeline",
            lgd_state_id="9",
            farm_health="100",
            updated_by_id="1",
            created_by_id="1",
            boundary_coord="[[28.61942190728406,77.42481022275172],[28.619423700462267,77.42536250193155],[28.61898976028526,77.42544314893678],[28.61895838039465,77.42481941041035],[28.61942190728406,77.42481022275172]]",
            farm_name="Vijay Kumar's farm - 20 acres",
            region_name="UTTAR PRADESH",
            batch_count="1",
            pending_tasks="0"
        )

    def test_farm(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.farm1.farmer_id, "1")
        self.assertEqual(self.farm1.farmer_name, "Vijay Kumar")
        self.assertEqual(self.farm1.irrigation_type, "drip")
        self.assertEqual(self.farm1.farm_type, "soil")
        self.assertEqual(self.farm1.franchise_type, "protected")
        self.assertEqual(self.farm1.total_acerage, "20")
        self.assertEqual(self.farm1.farm_status, "pipeline")
        self.assertEqual(self.farm1.lgd_state_id, "9")
        self.assertEqual(self.farm1.farm_health, "100")
        self.assertEqual(self.farm1.updated_by_id, "1")
        self.assertEqual(self.farm1.created_by_id, "1")
        self.assertEqual(self.farm1.boundary_coord, "[[28.61942190728406,77.42481022275172],[28.619423700462267,77.42536250193155],[28.61898976028526,77.42544314893678],[28.61895838039465,77.42481941041035],[28.61942190728406,77.42481022275172]]")
        self.assertEqual(self.farm1.farm_name, "Vijay Kumar's farm - 20 acres")
        self.assertEqual(self.farm1.region_name, "UTTAR PRADESH")
        self.assertEqual(self.farm1.batch_count, "1")
        self.assertEqual(self.farm1.pending_tasks, "0")

    def test_model(self):
        d = self.farm1
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(d, Farm))
        self.assertEqual(str(d), "Vijay Kumar's farm - 20 acres")

    def test_return(self):
        farm11 = Farm.objects.create(farm_name="Vijay Kumar's farm",farmer_id="1")
        farm11.save()

        self.assertEqual(str(farm11), "Vijay Kumar's farm")
```

If any can help with it that would be great

Thanks in advances

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/testing/ - good place to start, you've apparently done no testing so start from the start

Comment: I have done some testing, I have attached the file above have a look over the file name test_farm.py, Think before you write SIR.

Comment: Sorry my dude, your original post made it look very much like you had not done any testing yet, i've added an answer below to show an example of how you might test your update_batch_count method. You will know the rest of your code better and are likely able to create better tests for the rest! Good luck

Comment: @AdarshSrivastav looking at the original post you added, Henty was completely right about saying you haven't done any testing. Please read the guidelines at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a question. It looks like you're new to StackOverflow, but asking for help with something, then not including the code you have already written in your question is not great. Especially when individuals are taking the time out of their days to help you **for free**. I think Henty was very generous in giving you an answer after your response.

Comment: sorry dude @Henty, I am just frustrated I have been working on these test cases for a while, and it's taking much more time than I expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 good options i think for going forward with testing here, either you can use integration testing and test the results of these methods when they've been used in other parts of your program or you can unit test the methods individually. From what you've supplied an example could be:

```
def test_batch_count(self):
    for i in range(5):
        Batch.objects.create(farm_id=self.farm1, ...)

    self.farm1.update_batch_count()
    assert self.farm1.batch_count == 5
```

This test can be added to your current TestFarm and will test your update_batch_count method.

Comment: what is that 3 dot mean after farm1

Comment: your other Batch variables like start_date and batch_health, any you need when creating a Batch instance

Comment: In the future/if you intend to work on the project long term, factories are incredibly useful for testing so if you want to check them out have a look here https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/introduction.html

Comment: Thanks, man the test_batch_count worked thanks again, but when I am trying to test the pending task   

def test_pending_tasks(self):
        for i in range(5):
            BatchSOPManagement.objects.create(batch_id__farm_id=self.farm1, current_status=2,
                                              due_datetime__lt=datetime.today(), )

        #self.farm1.update_pending_tasks()
        self.batch_id.farm_id.update_pending_tasks()
        assert self.farm1.pending_tasks == 5

it shows an error 

BatchSOPManagement() got an unexpected keyword argument 'batch_id__farm_id'

Comment: could not test pending_tasks it shows some error

Comment: could be batch_id__farm_id. youd write this as batch__farm_id cause its a foreign key on the batch not the batch_id

Comment: still the same TypeError: BatchSOPManagement() got an unexpected keyword argument 'batch__farm_id'

Comment: OOOO sorry i read it wrong the first time, you cant assign like this unless you use factories. You would need to create batches first then the BatchSOPManagement. Also can you mark my answer as correct pls, rep is the only payment we get on here haha

Comment: how could I implement it